# Regex to find text after linebreak in URL

Tags: python, regex

I want to use regex to get a part of the string. I want to remove the kerberos and everything after it and get the `Username`

```
import re
text = 'Kerberos://DME.DMS.WORLD.DMSHEN/Username'
reg1 = re.compile(r"^((Kerberos?|ftp):\/)?\/?([^:\/\s]+)((\/\w+)*\/)([\w\-\.]+[^#?\s]+)(.*)?(#[\w\-]+)?$",text)
print(reg1)
```

**Output**
`Username`

I am new to regex and tried this regex but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Just `text[text.rindex('/')+1:]` should suffice. No?

Comment: What is the possible content of your string? Is username always the part after the last slash?

Comment: Username is just a variable. Thats why I want to remove everything before `/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex works just fine, but I am assuming you would like to make most of the groups non-capturing (you can do that by adding `?:` to each group.

It will give you the following:

```
re.match(r"^(?:(?:Kerberos?|ftp):\/)?\/?(?:[^:\/\s]+)(?:(\/\w+)*\/)(?P<u>[\w\-\.]+[^#?\s]+)(?:.*)?(?:#[\w\-]+)?$",t).group('u')
```

Also, for future reference, try using https://regex101.com/ , it has an easy way to test your regex + explanations on each part.

Comment: But this gives kerberos as output instead of username

Comment: you're right, updated my answer. this can probably be made shorter, but it works

Answer (score 0):

How about this simple one:

```
import re
text = 'Kerberos://DME.DMS.WORLD.DMSHEN/Username'
reg1 = re.findall(r"//.*/(.*)", text)
print(''.join(reg1))
# Username
```

Comment: just want Username  without [' ']

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can use split instead of regex

```
text = 'Kerberos://DME.DMS.WORLD.DMSHEN/Username'
m = text.split('/')[-1]
print m
```